# Kronecker Delta tensor proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors, kronecker-delta

How would I go about proving $\delta_{ij}$ is a rank 2 tensor? Help appreciated

EDIT: Tensor being defined by the following:

$$x'_i = L_{ij} x_j, x_i = L_{ji} x'_j \tag{7.7}$$

A *Cartestian Tensor* $T_{ij...l}$ of rank $r$ has $r$ indices and transforms under the special orthogonal transformation $(7.7)$ as

$T^{'}_{ij...l}$($x^{'}$) = $L_{ip}$$L_{jq}$...$L_{ls}$$T_{pq...s}$($L^{-1}$$x^{'}$)

Comment: What's your definition of a tensor? What thoughts/progress have you made?

Comment: The traditional definition of a Cartesian tensor, and no progress

Comment: Is it the transform a certain way under a change of basis definition, or the multidimensional array definition, or something with tensor products?

Comment: I've added the definition I was given

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\delta_{ij}$ is independent of the basis chosen. If $R$ is a rotation matrix, then since $R^\intercal R=I$, we get
$$R_{ip}R_{jq}\delta_{pq}=R_{ip}R_{jp}=\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ij}',$$
which is precisely the transformation rule for a rank $2$ tensor.